# snapper in open suse 42.3 leap creating lots of snapshots

Tags: opensuse, btrfs

I'm using openSuse as my desktop, prior to that i was using Ubuntu. My root (/) file system is btrfs and xfs for /home.

Whenever i try to run yast it is creating a pre and post snapshot even if there is no changes.

For example , If we are opening Hardware information in Yast. Which is not going to do any file system changes, except the harddisk attributes file modificaiton at /var/lib/smartmontools/

My Question is how do i tell to snapper ,Create snapshot only if there a real changes in certain folders (list of exclusion or list of inclusion). Because there are more snapshot. What is the optimal snapshot configuration.

I did the some changes in config /etc/snapper/configs/root  Please correct me if anything wrong.

```
/etc/snapper/configs/root

# subvolume to snapshot
SUBVOLUME="/"

# filesystem type
FSTYPE="btrfs"


# btrfs qgroup for space aware cleanup algorithms
QGROUP="1/0"


# fraction of the filesystems space the snapshots may use
SPACE_LIMIT="0.5"


# users and groups allowed to work with config
ALLOW_USERS=""
ALLOW_GROUPS=""

# sync users and groups from ALLOW_USERS and ALLOW_GROUPS to .snapshots
# directory
SYNC_ACL="no"


# start comparing pre- and post-snapshot in background after creating
# post-snapshot
BACKGROUND_COMPARISON="yes"


# run daily number cleanup
NUMBER_CLEANUP="yes"

# limit for number cleanup
NUMBER_MIN_AGE="1800"
NUMBER_LIMIT="2-10"
NUMBER_LIMIT_IMPORTANT="4-10"


# create hourly snapshots
TIMELINE_CREATE="no"

# cleanup hourly snapshots after some time
TIMELINE_CLEANUP="yes"

# limits for timeline cleanup
TIMELINE_MIN_AGE="1800"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_HOURLY="0"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_DAILY="2"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_WEEKLY="0"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_MONTHLY="0"
TIMELINE_LIMIT_YEARLY="0"


# cleanup empty pre-post-pairs
EMPTY_PRE_POST_CLEANUP="yes"

# limits for empty pre-post-pair cleanup
EMPTY_PRE_POST_MIN_AGE="1800"
```

Comment: [unix.se] would have been a better place to ask